# Select <TR> under HTML by VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

Hi Again The above code is working for week selection but not to select time

```html
<td style="white-space:nowrap;">Master Timings</td>
<td>
    <select name="ddlSTSun" id="ddlSTSun" onChange="return ChangeAllSTET(frmRosterInfoTLEmp,&#39;ddlSTSun&#39;,&#39;ddlST1Sun02&#39;);" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:9pt;">
        <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
        <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
        <option value="03:00">03:00</option>
        <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
        <option value="05:00">05:00</option>
        <option value="06:00">06:00</option>
        <option value="07:00">07:00</option>
```

My VBA code is

```
ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelector("[name=cmbWeeks]").selectedIndex = "Week:-2 19-May-2019"
ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelector("[name=cmbWeeks]").FireEvent ("onchange")
Sleep 5000
ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelector("[name=ddlSTSun]").selectedIndex = "12:00"
ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelector("[name=ddlSTSun]").FireEvent ("onchange")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an id so use that first-off. Then `selectedIndex` takes the index position e.g. 1,2 etc not the time value.

```
ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelector("#ddlSTSun").selectedIndex = 1
```

You can use an attribute=value selector to specify the time:

```
ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelector("#ddlSTSun [value='12:00']").selected = True
```

---

Event (if required):

```
ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelector("#ddlSTSun").FireEvent "onchange"
```